# AutoSuggestBox with Button in ItemTemplate

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to place a Button within the ItemTemplate of an AutoSuggestBox. However, it doesn't work as the Button's Click event is never triggered. I'm guessing it's because of the AutoSuggestBox loosing focus when the Button is pressed and thus the event is canceled?!

Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

```
<Grid>
    <AutoSuggestBox TextChanged="AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged">
        <AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                    <Button Content="Add" Click="Button_Click"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
    </AutoSuggestBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Why not using [SuggestionChosen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.autosuggestbox.suggestionchosen.aspx) event directly?

Comment: Because I wish to have two actions on the AutoSuggestBox. One that will take me to a details page of the selected item. And one that will add the  selected item to a list.